# What encryption scheme is supported by Java on most platforms out of the box?

Tags: java, cryptography

I've googled and I've experimented, and I'm having no luck.

I'm writing a program that talks between android, windows/linux java and a raspberry pi and I want to encrypt something on one side and decrypt on the other, in all directions, as in, I want it to work in each possible platform case.

Blowfish, and DES eventually give me the dreaded "Given final block not properly padded"
on one platform or another and AES goes so slow on the raspberry as to be useless.
I've tried various secretkeyfactorys and keygenerators, and everything my master-cut-and-paste skills allowed for, and nothing works.

Very frustrating, I'm considering using ROT13. At least I know that works.

I know somebody's going to ask for a code sample so here it is... it's the same exact code everybody else shows examples of.

```
   public static SecretKey generatedessecretkey(String password) throws InvalidKeyException, UnsupportedEncodingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException
      {
        DESKeySpec keySpec = new DESKeySpec(password.getBytes("UTF8"));
        SecretKeyFactory keyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("DES");
        SecretKey key = keyFactory.generateSecret(keySpec);
        return key;
      }

    public static void encrypt(IOLogger log, byte[] datablock, String grouppw, ArrayList<byte[]> resp)
      {
        try
          {
            SecretKey ks = generatedessecretkey(grouppw);
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES");
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, ks);
            byte[] b = cipher.doFinal(datablock);
            resp.clear();
            resp.add(b);
            return;
          }
        catch (Exception e)
          {
          }
      }
```

edit: here's the decrypt, it's the same thing backwards

```
 public static void desdecrypt(IOLogger log, byte[] datablock, String grouppw, ArrayList<byte[]> resp)
      {
        try
          {
            SecretKey ks = generatedessecretkey(grouppw);
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES");
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, ks);
            byte[] b = cipher.doFinal(datablock);
            resp.clear();
            resp.add(b);
            return;
          }
        catch (Exception e)
          {
          }
      }
```

Comment: Sounds like a comms or endian issue. Consider encrypting the same input on all platforms and do a byte-by-byte comparison. You may just need to pad, or transport the encrypted stream as base63 encoding, etc

Comment: Post your decryption code. This stuff works for everybody else. Obviously the problem is yours, not Java's. It's pointless to pretend otherwise. You could start by not ignoring exceptions. They often have strangely useful things to tell you.

Comment: Also, you *don't* call `doFinal` unless it's the last `datablock`.

Comment: It doesn't help that you catch all `Exception`'s and ignore them

Comment: Programming cryptography is like arming a bomb. It's difficult enough for a professional; it's unreasonable to expect a beginner to produce secure code. In this case you should probably use an existing protocol that's designed for this, like TLS or SSH. If you feel those are difficult to configure, I'd like to point out that writing your own protocol is at least 100 times harder.

Comment: ahhh, now we're on to something. First of all, this is a trimmed down version of the code in question. But elliot said you don't call dofinal unless it's the last datablock. Never heard this before. I'll go look that up, perhaps there's more to this than the code everybody's sharing. THanks for the tip.

Comment: @Bohemian I have a checksum on the pile of data going back and forth so it's definitely the same thing on both sides. I'll check out the padding though, thanks.

Comment: I think maybe the question I really want to ask is what encryption scheme is supported on most platforms out of the box so nobody has to install anything to make my application work. Or is there something I can include with my application written in java already.

Comment: Try running the message through md5 hash, which is sensitive to the numbers of bits digested, and compare hashes

Comment: Okay how's this: I got this brilliant idea to, on the client side, encrypt the packet, then make a copy and decrypt it just to verify that the packet was good, then I send it to the server, and decrypt the same exact packet. I switched to jasypt 1.9.2 to remove any chance of me getting anything wrong. packets encrypt and decrypt just fine for a while then all of a sudden one packet gets a org.jasypt.exceptions.EncryptionOperationNotPossibleException. Same place as when I wasn't using jasypt. I dump the packet on both sides, they're 104 bytes and identical. Ideas?

Comment: okay EJP was right, and I kinda knew it, it had to be something of mine, and it was. After many days of banging head on table, I finally figured out that in some cases, the password being used to encrypt was different than the password being used to decrypt. I spent so much effort trying to find problems with the encrypted data, I never thought to look at the password. Thanks for all the effort, guys.

Answer (score 0):

> the question I really want to ask is what encryption scheme is supported on most platforms out of the box

That question is answered in full by the [JCA Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/crypto/CryptoSpec.html) and the list of standard algorithms given [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/StandardNames.html).

It seems to me that you just haven't specified the chaining and padding modes correctly, or at all.